# How to call a Service/ API Asynchronously

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to invoke a service/ API asynchronously and I noticed the thread get blocked when I invoke the service which behaves like a synchronous.

How can I call a service/ API asynchronously?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to API Manager, all the API invocations are, by default, asynchronous. Once the Gateway receives a request, it passes it to the backend and releases the thread for accepting other requests.

If you are referring to ESB/ Integrator, then you can use the Call mediator to invoke services/ APIs either asynchronously or synchronously. The Call mediator has a properly called, Blocking which can be used to control the mode - asynchronously or synchronously. Blocking set to `true` means it behaves in synchronous mode.

For more information - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/reference/mediators/call-mediator/

Comment: What's the default mode of this setting when we use the Call mediator? Is it blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: @Eva default mode of the call mediator is non-blocking

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you are tring to achieve. If you want to do multiple calls at the same time. You can use the [Clone Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/clone-Mediator/).

```xml
<clone xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <target>
      <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_73A47733EB1E6F30812921609540392-849227072">
         <default />
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <target sequence="test1" />
</clone>
```